# How to fix mat-checkbox animation hang/freeze when content is rendering in Angular2+?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-animations

I use mat-checkbox (angular material UI 7.2) in my Angular 7 application.
There are some site content generations when I click mat-checkbox.
There are only 10 ngFor items (complex) in my real application.

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="onChange()">Check me! (bad animation)</mat-checkbox>
<span *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{item}}
</span>
```

I make a very simplified example with many ngFor simple items to demonstrate my problem.

```
  public items = [];

  public onChange(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      this.items.push(i);
    }
  }
```

This example you can find here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-kq3s3a

**When I click mat-checkbox, animation of checkbox hang and looks very bad.**
Is there a possibility to fix this mat-checkbox hang/freeze animation in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ChangeDetectorRef` in `@angular/core`.

Using `ChangeDetectorRef` like that,

add detector in your constructor

```
constructor(....,
    private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

and `this.cdr.detectChanges()` where you want

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-design-jc8vzp)

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer, actually I don't see a difference, checkbox animation still is hang/freeze...  maybe have any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, setTimeout solve the problem, but maybe is there some other way? because user need wait extra 500ms for see items. If there are no other possibilities, I will acept this answer later

Comment: You can use waiting gif,if you can. like updating answer link